# Adding custom header to generated WebService helper

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, webforms, asmx

Is the a way to add or customize the headers when using the generated javascript that is created from .asmx files?

For example I have a webservice like:
SomeService.asmx

```
[WebService(Namespace = "https://www.somedomain.com/api/someapi", Description = "api", Name = "someapi")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ScriptService]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    [HttpPost]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public List<SomeModel> GetData(string SomeArgument)
    {
        string customHeaderValue = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.Get("SomeCustomHeader");
        // Do things
    }

}
```

Now using jQuery I can specify the custom header like:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Path/ToFile/Webservice.asmx/GetData',
    data: "data",
    success: OnSuccessFunc,
    error: OnFailureFunc,
    headers: {
        'SomeCustomHeader': "SomeCustomHeaderValue" <---
    }
});
```

But I know that the asmx files can generate some helper functions javascript that will handle everything for me. For example if I add

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Path/ToFile/Webservice.asmx/js"></script>
```

then on the page i can simply write

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   Webservice.GetData("data", OnSuccessFunc, OnFailureFunc)
</script>
```

But how would I include the custom header data using the generated javascript version?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to setup a header to every request using  beforeSend hook with $.ajaxSetup()

Take a look at this URL.
https://www.edureka.co/community/82342/how-to-add-custom-http-header-to-ajax-request-with-javascript